# Parse a string containing a Unicode number into the corresponding Unicode character?

Tags: rust

Is there a function to do something like this:

```
fn string_to_unicode_char(s: &str) -> Option<char> {
    // ...
}

fn main() {
    let s = r"\u{00AA}";  // note the raw string literal!
    string_to_unicode_char(s).unwrap();
}
```

Note that `r"\u{00AA}"` uses a [raw string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#raw-string-literals) i. e. it isn't a *Unicode sequence* but 8 separate symbols, as `\` `u` `{` `0` `0` `A` `A` `}`.

I need to interpret/convert/parse this string and return a char if all is good, `None` otherwise. I don't have any experience with Unicode, so any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Be careful about the notion of “unicode character”. It's not easy to define, and certainly is not the same as `char` (which is a unicode scalar value). Eg “ɔ̃” is one character, but two `char`s.

Comment: @mcarton you are right, but I think I don't need so exotic symbols, `unicode scalar` is enough

Comment: With respect to the update about raw strings, please describe the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the function you are looking for is [`char::from_u32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/char/fn.from_u32.html):

```
fn string_to_unicode_char(s: &str) -> Option<char> {
    // Do something more appropriate to find the actual number
    let number = &s[3..7];

    u32::from_str_radix(number, 16)
        .ok()
        .and_then(std::char::from_u32)
}

fn main() {
    let s = r"\u{00AA}";  // note the raw string literal!
    let ch = string_to_unicode_char(s);
    assert_eq!(ch, Some('\u{00AA}'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*I indeed completely misunderstood your question; my old answer can be seen in the [edit logs](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40056782/revisions)*

> Is there a builtin function to parse a string containing a Rust unicode escape into the corresponding unicode character?

AFAIK, **no**, there is not a builtin function to do that.

The answer to "how to do it yourself" is a bit broad, as there are many ways to do it (and it's not clear whether you also want to parse standard escapes, such as `"\n"`).

- Use a regex
- Do simple, naive manual parsing
- Embed it into a bigger lexer ([the function in the Rust compiler parsing such unicode escapes](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9e3dcb45493366c790d333aaf4dfa5a043e49a63/src/libsyntax/parse/lexer/mod.rs#L959-L1014))